# Counter intuitive meaning of < ANY & >ANY logic operators in SQL

Tags: sql

`ANY` intuitively means: anything that matches in the set.
However, I found out it, it doesn't behave as expected in two cases:

> `x > ANY(...)` The value must be greater than the smallest value in
>   the list to evaluate to TRUE.
>   `x < ANY(...)` The value must be
>   smaller than the biggest value in the list to evaluate to TRUE

([Source](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql.php))

In other words, the entire result of sub-query introduced by `ANY` has to be compared to `x`, which runs counter to meaning of `ANY`.
Why is it so, or I am just misunderstanding the semantics of `<ANY` & `>ANY` operators ?

Comment: `ANY` behaves as `ANY`. What you mean when say "Any of them ..."? Do you mean "All of them"? In addition look at [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/any)

Comment: For me it's the correct meaning. But you will hardly see a query using ANY/ALL because it's most DBMSes don't implement it and it can be easily rewritten in a more readable query (IMHO). E.g. you don't write "x = ANY" instead of "x IN"

Comment: You are using `ANY` and expecting the functionality of `ALL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x > ANY(...)` The value must be greater than the smallest value in the list to evaluate to TRUE.
`x < ANY (...)` The value must be smaller than the biggest value in the list to evaluate to TRUE

Both of the above statements assert the Algorithm that oracle might using for comparison. for example.

```
select * from X where id > Any ( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 )
```

in above code can be drill down as

```
id > 1  OR  id > 2  OR id > 3 and so on..
```

so only id > 1 will assert it true. (Algo Optimization)  Same way they did it for `x < ANY (...)`

Answer (score 1):

> `x > ANY(...)` The value must be greater than the smallest value in the list to evaluate to `TRUE`

This is stating a consequence. It may take some thinking about. `x` *may* be greater than *every* value in the list, and it will still return `TRUE`. The opposite may be easier to understand:

`x > ANY(...)` will be `FALSE` if the value is less than or equal to the smallest value in the list, because it must also be less than or equal to all other members of the list

Or yet another way:

`x > ANY(...)` will be true if there is at least one value in the list, `y` say, that `x` is greater than. If there are a set of such `y` values, the smallest value in the list must logically be one member of that set.